# In KnovaJs, How to allow Rect to expand with Text or Allow Text to Have Border That Expand With Text Like If its Div in Html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

I am having trouble to see an easy to apply solution so that, a `Rect` can be a container for `Text`, just like a  in Html as a container for a , so that if a div has a border, it will expand with the text as text increase in counts.

I haven't be able to do it through either `Rect` With `Text` in a `Group` or apply `Label` above a `Text`...

Is that even doable? If not, what is the alternative that I can somehow let the Rect smartly detect the size of Text in the same `Group` so it expands accordingly?

I am using Konva by utilizing `konva-react`

Answer (score 2):

`Konva.Label` is very useful for that use case.

```
      <Label>
        <Tag fill="red" />
        <Text text="hello" />
      </Label>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/84mzo6l5k0

If you want to use `Konva.Rect` + `Konva.Text` you have to calculate the size of the text manually and then apply it to the rectangle instance.

Comment: Just curious, is there an easy way to calculate the size of a sentence in which multiple fonts are used, i.e. a rich text sentence ?

Comment: I know fill works, but the key feature is *border*  which tag does not support... which is ... strange in my opinion lol @lavrton

Comment: @VanquishedWombat there is no simple way for that. You have to calculate each font manually and then sum.

Comment: @Ezeewei you should use `stroke` property. It works ok.